# Magento2: unable to call catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml in magento2?

Tags: overrides, magento-2.2.5, downloadable

I have override the `catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml` in my module as

```
MyVendor/Downloadable/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml
```

But unable to call the changes done in **xml** file it only calls the default `catalog_product_view.xml`.

**Can anyone help me to find reason for error in xml file.**

**catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="custom-downloadable-product"/>

    <referenceContainer name="product.info.addtocart.additional" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="product.price.final.copy" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.price" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.downloadable.samples" remove="true"/>


    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info" remove="true" />
</body>
```

**module.xml**

```
<module name="MyVendor_Downloadable" setup_version="1.0.8">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Downloadable"/>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Comment: please add your xml code

Comment: U can check now

Comment: did you run all required commands

Comment: @magefms yes i run all required commands

Comment: how do you define dependency in your module sequence?

Comment: @magefms please check module sequence in code

Comment: did you try to remove var folder and flus cache. you have defined dependency correctly

Comment: Yes i tried everything, code works fine in local server but issue generated in production server